# order objects by given values

Tags: c#, linq

Given:

```
class C
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
}
template = new [] { "str1", "str2", ... }.ToList() // presents allowed values for C.Field1 as well as order
list = new List<C> { ob1, ob2, ... }
```

Question:

How can I perform Linq's

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.Field1)
```

which will use template above for order (so objects with `Field1 == "str1"` come first, than objects with `"str2"` and so on)?

Answer (score 2):

In LINQ to Object, use [`Array.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var ordered = list
    .Select(x => new { Obj = x, Index = Array.IndexOf(template, x.Field1)})
    .OrderBy(p => p.Index < 0 ? 1 : 0) // Items with missing text go to the end
    .ThenBy(p => p.Index)              // The actual ordering happens here
    .Select(p => p.Obj);               // Drop the index from the result
```

This wouldn't work in EF or LINQ to SQL, so you would need to bring objects into memory for sorting.

**Note:** The above assumes that the list is *not* exhaustive. If it is, a simpler query would be sufficient:

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(template, x.Field1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `IndexOf` might work here:

```
list.OrderBy(_ => Array.IndexOf(template, _.Field1))
```

Please note that it will return -1 when object is not present at all, which means it will come first. You'll have to handle this case. If your field is guaranteed to be there, it's fine.

Comment: This is the better answer, because you mention the possible problem of a missing template value!

Comment: @RomanoZumbé although the comment in the OP's code says `presents allowed values for Ljo.Field1 as well as order`, so presumably they believe it to be complete.

Comment: @MattBurland That is correct, but I always try to keep in mind, that other people might come along here, too. So the explanation should also cover possible pifalls and be broad enough to be applied to similar problems

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `Array.IndexOf` should do the job just fine. However, if `template` is long and or `list` is long, it might be worthwhile transforming your `template` into a dictionary. Something like:

```
var templateDict = template.Select((item,idx) => new { item, idx })
                           .ToDictionary(k => k.item, v => v.idx);
```

(or you could just start by creating a dictionary instead of an array in the first place - it's more flexible when you need to reorder stuff)

This will give you a dictionary keyed off the string from template with the index in the original array as your value. Then you can sort like this:

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => templateDict[x.Field1]);
```

Which, since lookups in a dictionary are `O(1)` will scale better as `template` and `list` grow.

Note: The above code assumes all values of `Field1` are present in `template`. If they are not, you would have to handle the case where `x.Field1` isn't in `templateDict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(d => Array.IndexOf(template, d.MachingColumnFromTempalate) < 0 ? int.MaxValue : Array.IndexOf(template, d.MachingColumnFromTempalate)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Romano, I was trying to figure out out to make it look like that. xD

Comment: You do `IndexOf` twice? That's pretty needlessly inefficient

Comment: I was pretty sure it was to move all those items to last of the ordered list which wasn't there in template, please enlighten me if I was wrong. @matt

Comment: I know _why_ you are doing it. But it is needlessly inefficient. `IndexOf` is `O(n)` and you are doing it twice. Worse case you have to search through all of `template` to find that it's the last item in the list, and then do it again to get the actual index because you threw it away. It's a simple fix: `var idx = Array.IndexOf(template, d.Field1); return idx < 0 ? int.MaxValue : idx;` - only uses `IndexOf` once.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I've actually written a method to do this before. Here's the source:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderToMatch<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> sortKeySelector, IEnumerable<TKey> ordering)
{
    var orderLookup = ordering
        .Select((x, i) => new { key = x, index = i })
        .ToDictionary(k => k.key, v => v.index);

    if (!orderLookup.Any())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Ordering collection cannot be empty.", nameof(ordering));
    }

    T[] sourceArray = source.ToArray();

    return sourceArray
        .OrderBy(x =>
        {
            int index;
            if (orderLookup.TryGetValue(sortKeySelector(x), out index))
            {
                return index;
            }
            return Int32.MaxValue;
        })
        .ThenBy(x => Array.IndexOf(sourceArray, x));
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
 var ordered = list.OrderToMatch(x => x.Field1, template);
```

If you want to see the source, the unit tests, or the library it lives in, you can [find it on GitHub](https://github.com/anaximander23/Anaximander.Linq/blob/master/src/Anaximander.Linq.Shared/IEnumerableExtensions.cs). It's also available as a NuGet package.